# Using a CDN to load React

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React App that I'm trying to load through using a CDN vs NPM.

My `options.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Test Extension Options</title>
    <script src="https://fb...me/react-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fb...me/react-dom-0.14.2.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello world</div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

When I load up `options.html` in a browser, nothing is showing up when I expected to see Hello world. I checked the debugger and no errors are coming up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I may be wrong, but don't you have to transform your JSX into plain JavaScript in this case? JSX itself is not valid JavaScript

Comment: isn't that what `type="text/babel"` does?

Comment: You need to include Babel in this case, but it is not in list of your includes

Comment: I thought bye putting `type="text/babel"` I am including it?

Comment: No, Babel is just a JavaScript transpiler, not is not bundled into browsers, you have to include it manually in the same way as you include React

Comment: `type="text/babel"` just tells Babel that this script should be transpiled and replaced. By this same reason browser skips it (he have no information about how to handle such MIME type)

Answer (score 0):

I believe :

There is no need of type="text/babel"

```
<script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

so it should be

```
<script src="index.js" ></script>
```